# Criar array dinamicamente enquanto se digita e excluir quando o valor for em branco?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testeCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="(keyColumn, column) in columns">
            <li>{{ column.name }}
                <div ng-repeat="method in requireMethods">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="column.validation.messages[$index][method]" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <pre>{{ columns | json }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('testeCtrl',function($scope){
    var requireMethods = ['required','remote','maxlength']
    $scope.columns = [{
        name: 'teste',
        validation: {
            messages: []
        }
    },
        {
            name: 'teste1',
            validation: {
                messages: []
            }
        },
    ];
    $scope.requireMethods = requireMethods;
});
```

Entre no Jsfiddle para entender melhor:
https://jsfiddle.net/vosnwb1s/1/

```
"name": "teste1",
    "validation": {
    "messages": [
        null,
        null,
        {
            "maxlength": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Cheguei nessa solução, porém a array está criando `null` dependendo do lugar que você digitar no `input` de texto.
Gostaria de saber como eu excluo o `objeto` quando o valor for igual a vazio, por exemplo:

```
{
    "maxlength": "Digitado"
}
```

Quando o `maxlenght: ""`, excluir da array de objetos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar no `change` da entrada se a propriedade é vazia, se sim, ao invés de usar [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para remove o objeto do array de messages:

```
// indexPai é referente ao index de colums.
// index é referente ao index de messages
// method para saber se o valor da propriedade esta vazia    
$scope.remover = function(indexPai, index, method){
  if ( ! $scope.columns[indexPai].validation.messages[index][method] )
    $scope.columns[indexPai].validation.messages.splice(index,1);
}
```

> O método splice() altera o conteúdo de uma lista, adicionando novos
>   elementos enquanto remove elementos antigos.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/vosnwb1s/3/